# can i write form action method in if loop? in smarty template?

Tags: model-view-controller, smarty

```
 $router->map('people_companies_add_owner', 'people/add/:is_owner','null', array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'add','is_owner'=>'1'));
   $router->map('people_companies_add_client', 'people/add/:is_owner','null', array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'add','is_owner'=>'0'));
```

which calls controller, showing add template. in controller I m getting parameter passed tht is "is_owner".which can again be accessible by add template but when it is rerouted it calls,

```
{form action='?route=people_companies_add' method=post}
```

{include_template name=_profile_form controller=companies module=system}

I want to check the "is_owner" flag and accordingly call owner or client.can I put form action in if loop?? like

if($n==1)
form action=?route=peple_com_owner
else
form action=?route=peple_com_client

It is showing smarty error

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    <form 
          method="post" 
          action="?route={if $is_owner}people_com_owner{else}people_com_client{/if}"
    >
```